# Why I can't search from the Dash on Amazon anymore on 13.04?

Tags: scopes, amazon

I know a lot of people were not happy with the search functionality from Amazon being added to Ubuntu but I was really pleased with it till now -- it stopped working. Since upgrading to 13.04 I am no longer able to search for products using the Dash. Did that feature get canned?

Comment: If you go to `Privacy` under `System Settings`, do you have online search results disabled by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

You should know that this feature has not been disabled, it didn't stop to work, it is still installed and ready to use by default on Raring Ringtail.

So you should have a problem with your internet connection or with the specific package.